# WCF Over HTTPS (Message & Transport) 404 Error (Page Not Found)

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I've WCF service that is working great with authentication and Message Security Type.

But I need to communicate with the WCF over https (its have to be in the url), so I need to add Transport Security Type.

(I'm using self sign certificate)

**This is my binding config:**

```
 <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**This is my Services config :**

```
  <services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost/Service1.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

**This is my Behavior config:**

```
  <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />

      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.UserValidate,WcfService1"/>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

**But like a true WCF Service nothing goes smooth:**

- When I execute the WCF its automatically open the page : "http://localhost:22535/" in the browser instead of https like I specified in the base address.
- When I open the page (no https) "http://localhost:22535/Service1.svc" I get the error :

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

- When I try to reach the page "https://localhost/Service1.svc" which I specified in the base address i get:

> This webpage is not available

**This is my entire Web.Config :**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost/Service1.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

           <!--My Custom Behavior-->
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />

          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.UserValidate,WcfService1"/>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance.

### Update

I've set the IIS application to bind on Https (Thanks Daniel Holmkviste).

Now I get 404 (not found) for the base address. ("https://localhost/Service1.svc")

But the good news I have a green lock and when I press it i see "LocalHost" with identity verified.

But why now it cant find the page ?

The Http (the automatically URL address when execute the wcf from the VS) "http://localhost:22535/Service1.svc" still give this error :

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Comment: To save yourself from headaches with WCF you can use SoapUI to know about service requirements and read service response with Fiddler. Can you post the WSDL?

Comment: @E-Bat I cant access the url "path + ?WSDL" I get the "Could not find a base address that matches..."

Comment: Please try using basichttpbinding instead of WSHttpbinding

Comment: Why is that ? @rauts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! the answer is to **turn the HTTP Activation On.**

Search "Turn Windows Features on or off" in windows.

Open `.NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services`

Open `WCF Services`

Check `HTTP Activation`

Answer (score 0):

Specify the metadata.

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetaDataExchange"/>
```

To enable https in VS you have to configure the properties of your project to use IIS.

Comment: Do one more thing-  Open IIS -> your website -> Advanced Settings -> Enabled Protocols -> add ,https

Comment: Try to give an address in address attribute of endpoint and then access the service with the new address